# ASP.NET page caching as relates to master?

Tags: asp.net, caching, master-pages

If I set cache on an ASP.NET page and have content, a control, in the master page then is that cached, as well?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't really understand your question, but here is a great resource on outputcaching, and in particular caching only certain items on a page. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Different portions of a page may be cached separately. However, if the cachability is set to either Public or Private, then the whole page, including the master page, will be cached, because the client browser or proxy servers that are doing the caching will be unable to distinguish between a normal page and a master page.

Answer (score 0):

Master Page and the page will be cached.